# Show that $(x-1)^2\geq x(\ln{x})^2, x>0$.

Tags: analysis, derivatives

> Show that $(x-1)^2\geq x(\ln{x})^2, x>0$.

In this type of problem, I usually transform the given inequality into a form of $f(x)<f(0)$ or $f(x)>\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$. Then use the derivative of $f$ to check whether $f(x)$ is strictly increasing or decreasing. But for this problem I struggle to find out the appropriate function $f$. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: try f(x) > f(1)

Comment: Hint: $$
x(\ln x)^2  = (x - 1)^2  - \int_1^x {\frac{{\ln t}}{{t^2 }}(x - t)^2 {\rm d}t} .
$$ Consider $0<x<1$ and $x\ge 1$ separately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $x > -1 \implies x^2 \ge (1+x)(\log(1+x))^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2661709/proving-x-1-implies-x2-ge-1x-log1x2)